# Two-factor authentication not working in PMA 5.00

Tags: phpmyadmin, two-factor-authentication

After upgrading from PMa 4.X to 5.00 (latest stable to date), I noticed two-factor authentication stopped working. It looks like it was not configured, despite PMA reporting successful configuration. 
I tried

- deleting all PMA related cookies,
- disabling and re-enabling two-factor (with Google Authenticator),
- generating new secret key in the process, checked that the new secret is saved properly in "userconfig" table (it is).

Percieved wrong behavior: PMA never asks for code, logs in directly. 
Expected: being asked to input code before logging in.

There are no error messages, including Apache logs. Also, during configuring two-factor, QR code is not shown, just an empty square, I do not know, if this is related. Everything else seems to be working properly. Thank you for suggestions.

```
Apache/2.4.41 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.2.26; 5.7.28-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue was solved in [4.9.4](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/milestone/255?closed=1) and 5.0.1

See [this issue on our tracker](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/15724)

Comment: It was fixed. I will more patient next time or at least I'll try. Please close this thread as solved, thank you all.

Comment: Yes, of course, but there's no such an option, at least for me ;)